# Why i can't add users to OU, from CSV File?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i am running a script to create AD users from CSV, but it returns an error

```
New-ADUser : The server is unwilling to process the request
   At C:\CreateADUsersFromCSV_expanded.ps1:19 char:1
   + New-ADUser `
    + ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Mike Terry,O...racademy,DC=com 
   :String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirector 
   y.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

THE SCRIPT IS THAT:

```
# Import the AD Module

Import-Module ActiveDirectory


$filepath = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the path to the CSV file that contains the new user accounts"

$users = Import-CSV $filepath

ForEach ($user in $users) {

New-ADUser `
-Name ($user.'First Name' + " " + $user.'Last Name') `
-GivenName $user.'First Name' `
-Surname $user.'Last Name' `
-UserPrincipalName ($user.'First Name' + "." + $user.'Last Name') `
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "P@$$w0rd123" -AsPlainText -Force) `
-Description $user.Description `
-EmailAddress $user.'Email Address' `
-Title $user.'Job Title' `
-OfficePhone $user.'Office Phone' `
-Path $user.'Organizational Unit' `

}
```

THE ERROR APPEARS AT THE LINE

-Path $user.'Organizational Unit' `

THE CSV FILE IS LIKE THAT:

[image]

Comment: Why is there a continuation mark after the last line?

Comment: Remove the backtick from last line after 'Organizational Unit'  The backtick indicates more parameter are on the next line and you do not have any more parameters.

Comment: @jdweng Ok, i removed it, but the error still occurs

Comment: Try commenting out -Path and see if it works.  The property may not exist.

Comment: Yes, with comment to -Path it works.

Comment: You have a typo, `Domain Users` is a container not an OU. In your Csv, you should use `CN=Domain Users...` instead of `OU=Domain Users...`

Comment: Tip: use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) and stop using those horrible backticks

Comment: @Theo, I am new to power shell scripting, thanks for your tip

Comment: I also assume you have the rights to do that.  I don't.  Also our path looks like this:  `OU=People,DC=stackoverflow,DC=com`.

Comment: This script It's from online courses and labs about Windows Server.The script i wanted to run to my own virtual machine, so still learning things

Comment: This is most likely due to `-UserPrincipalName ($user.'First Name' + "." + $user.'Last Name')` - the UPN has to have the format `userpart@<valid-upn-suffix>`, so attempting to set one without the `@<valid-upn-suffix>` part will certainly cause the DSA to reject the request

Comment: If you add the CSV as actual text in a table instead of a picture, it will be easier to read and use for replicating your issue.

Comment: The error occurs when i leave without comment, the line "-Path $user.'Organizational Unit'" .I think that i haven't set the corrent OU and Containers to save users from that CSV file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/115aOeatk9k5_YpdEtfqrewAQLwHk4hFI/view?usp=drive_link Here is the actual csv file

Comment: I set this for path "CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=serveracademy,DC=com" at csv file
and creates users inside the "Users" Container

Comment: Open ADUC (Active Directory Users and Computers tool) and select the OU you want the new users to go to. Right-click that OU and select `Properties`. Scroll down to the `DistinguishedName` and copy the value. Use that for the `Organizational Unit` field in your CSV

Comment: @Theo Yes, i've done this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please set the "accountpassword" parameter to another value with min. special characters as permitted by your domain policy and without "$" (dollar sign) character.

Pls note that this workaround is only to find the root cause of the script error. This is not a general recommendation of course.